# Elasticsearch routing issues with Parent-child - objects are stored in different shards

Tags: elasticsearch

Parent & Child objects are being stored in different shards

Here is how I'm implementing the Parent and child objects.

I've custom routing parameter for my parent object.
Parent ID is specified while adding child object.

If there is no custom routing parameter, everything works just fine. But if I specify custom routing parameter to my Parent object, child objects are not stored in same shard, which is causing the search queries to fail.

Is there a way to fix the issue without forcing the custom routing value on Child ?

I'm using ES 1.0 Beta2 version .

Thanx

Answer (score 4):

By default the parent document uses its `_id` as the routing value, and the child document uses the value of `parent` as its routing value.  The value of `parent` is the same as the `_id` of the parent, so they end up on the same shard.

If you use a custom `routing` value on the parent, then you need to specify it on the `child` as well, eg:

```
PUT /myindex/parent/1?routing=custom_val
{...}

PUT /myindex/child/2?parent=1&routing=custom_val
{...}
```

An alternative is to use an alias with a configured routing value:

```
PUT /myindex/_alias/myalias
{ "routing": "custom_value" }
```

Then you can index into the alias instead, without specifying the `routing` on every request:

```
PUT /myalias/parent/1
{...}

PUT /myalias/child/2?parent=1
{...}
```